# Why do objects always stick together in perfectly inelastic collisions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, collision

From what I understand, perfectly inelastic collisions are those in which the maximum possible amount of kinetic energy is lost from the system. This means that the kinetic energy after the collision must be minimized. If this is true, then for the case in which an object with a constant velocity crashes into a stationary object, why is the post-collision kinetic energy minimized when the two objects stick together?

Comment: *" This means that the kinetic energy after the collision must be minimized."* This is not a good definition unless you append some verbiage like *"consistent with the conservation of momentum"* which also puts you on the track to answering your own question. (Note that if you examine the system in the center of momentum frame then they extra phase has no effect and the final net macroscopic KE *is* zero.)

Comment: Why does the definition need to take into account the conservation of momentum?

Comment: When you say "crashes into a stationary object", do you mean something like slamming into and sticking to a wall?

Comment: @dmckee "the final net macroscopic KE is zero". How do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: I meant like a block colliding into another block that isn't moving.

Comment: @Stewie Because momentum must be conserved.

Comment: @BobD Pehaps my comment is not clear. I'm discussing a fully inealstic collisiton viewed in the CoM frame.

Comment: @dmckee Are you saying the center of mass does not move after the collision?

Comment: @dmckee What if the momentum isn't conserved though?

Comment: To apply the terminology of and methods of "collisions" you should be examining a system where momentum is conserved (either because external forces are absent or because the evert happens too fast for the magnitude of external forces present to matter). That is, the rules of "collisions" are defined with that assumption built in. Events that don't qualify for the assumption don't follow these rules, but also don't get discussed with these terms.

Comment: @BobD In the center of momentum frame, yes. That's one way to *define* the center of momentum frame. Read the sentence where you found that phrase: I suggest a different way of looking at the system than the OP posits; one where his original phrasing would be valid.

Comment: @Stewie, when Newton's 3rd law applies (it always does), momentum MUST be conserved.

Comment: @dmckee Alright, that makes sense. But, when one object collides with another object that is not moving, why does the fact they stick together minimize the post-collision kinetic energy? Is there a way to show that the two objects sticking together will lead to the lowest possible kinetic energy still following the conservation of momentum?

Comment: You can decompose the kinetic energy of a system into a kinetic energy of the center of mass plus the kinetic energy of the parts relative the center of mass. All outcomes have to have the same value for the first term (because of the conservation of momentum), and the lowest value for the second term comes when none of the parts are moving relative the CoM. Showing that you can perform the decomposition doesn't require any math you don't have, but the development isn't obvious and the bookkeepping is a little involved at first; you can find it worked in any junior-level mechanics book.

Comment: @dmckee Where can I find a worked out version of this? Any books or websites? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the center of momentum frame:

$$ \vec p_1 = - \vec p_2 \equiv \vec p$$

The total energy is:

$$ T = \frac{p^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p^2}{2m_2} $$

After the collision:

$$ \vec p_1' = -\vec p_2' \equiv \vec p' $$

and the kinetic energy is:

$$ T' = \frac{p'^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p'^2}{2m_2} =p'^2(\frac 1 {2m_1}+\frac 1 {2m_2})$$

which is clearly minimized by:

$$ p' = 0 $$

which implies the 2 masses have no relative motion.

Comment: so it it not a requirement that the two objects ahdere to each other, so long at they leave the collision traveling together

Comment: exactly. They could smash, deform, stick, and have internal energy (heat). One could have a massless spring that catches the other and latches, storing the energy as potential energy, or the spring could oscillate and be considered an internal degree of freedom of the new system formed form the combined masses. The $T-T'$ does have to go somewhere, though.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, perfectly inelastic collisions are those in
>   which the maximum possible amount of kinetic energy is lost from the
>   system. This means that the kinetic energy after the collision must be
>   minimized.

In an inelastic collision the amount of kinetic energy that is lost has to be consistent with conservation of momentum, as @dmckee has pointed out, since momentum is always conserved.

> If this is true, then for the case in which an object with a constant
>   velocity crashes into a stationary object, why is the post-collision
>   kinetic energy minimized when the two objects stick together?

The amount of kinetic energy remaining after the collision will always be less, but the actual amount of the loss will depend on the relative masses of the colliding objects.

Consider the following completely inelastic collision between two masses. The velocities and kinetic energies are all with respect to the initial rest frame of the initially stationary object, that is, the rest frame of you the observer.

Let an object of mass $m_1$ and initial velocity $v_i$ collide with and stick to a mass $m_2$ initially at rest. Let $v_f$ be the final velocity of the two masses stuck together after the collision.  Then, for conservation of momentum we have.

$$m_{1}v_{i}=(m_{1}+m_{2})v_f$$

The final velocity of the combined masses after the collision is then

$$v_{f}=\frac{m_1}{(m_{1}+m_2)}v_i$$

The initial kinetic energy of the system is

$$KE_{i}=\frac{m_{1}v^{2}}{2}$$

The final kinetic energy of the system following the collision will be

$$KE_{f}=\frac{1}{2}(m_{1}+m_{2})v_{f}^2$$

Substituting for $v_f$ and rearranging the final kinetic energy is

$$KE_{f}=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(\frac{m_1}{1+m_{2}/m_{1}}\biggl)v_{i}^2$$

Note that if $m_1$=$m_2$ the final KE will be half the original. If $m_{1}$>>>$m_{2}$ the final kinetic energy approaches the initial. On the other hand, if $m_1$<<<$m_2$, The final kinetic energy approaches zero. But for all cases kinetic energy will be lost.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With no external forces acting the linear momentum of a system is constant.

With your two masses one of which is moving let’s take out the linear momentum of the system of the two masses which cannot change.
This is the linear momentum of the centre of mass of the system.
You are then left with two particles in the centre of mass reference frame with a total of zero linear momentum.

The kinetic energy of the centre of mass of the system cannot be changed but the kinetic energy of the two particles in the centre of mass frame of reference can.
What is the greatest reduction there can be in the kinetic energy of the two particles in the centre of mass reference frame?
The one in which before the collision the particles move and have a total linear momentum of zero to one where the two particles joining together and are at rest in the centre of mass reference frame.

So the centre of mass of the two particles carries all the linear momentum of the system and a certain amount of the kinetic energy of the system which cannot be changed if there are no external forces acting on the system.
What is “left over” as the kinetic energy of the particles in the centre of mass frame of reference can be reduced to zero leaving the particles at rest in this frame of reference.
Such a collision is the one which you referred to as a “perfectly inelastic collision”.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question 2 years later because I think it may help others who see this post.

> From what I understand, perfectly inelastic collisions are those in which the maximum possible amount of kinetic energy is lost from the system.

Yes you are right!
The loss in kinetic energy depends upon the coefficient of restituton $e$.
$$\Delta K.E. = \frac{m_1m_2(u_1-u_2)^{2}(1-e^{2})}{m_1+m_2}$$
Thus $$\Delta K.E. \propto (1-e^2)$$ and maximum value of  $(1-e^2)$ is $1$ when $e = 0$ and thus when $(1-e^2)$ is max. then $\Delta K.E.$ is also max. and thjs proves in a **perfectly inelastic collision** coefficient of restitution: $$e =0$$
Now,$$e=\frac{v_2-v_1}{u_1-u_2} = 0$$
Therefore,
$$v_2-v_1 = 0 \implies v_2 = v_1$$ or we know that $(v_2-v_1)$ is **velocity of separation**(velocity with which the two bodies separate after collision).
Thus,
$$\mathbb{velocity\, of \, separation =0 }$$
Which means that bodies did not separate after collision and they stick together after collision and move as a single body of mass $m_1 + m_2$.
For reference:
$m_1,m_2$ = mass of the two bodies
$u_1,u_2$ = initial velocities of two bodies before collision
$v_1,v_2$ = final velocities of two bodies after collision.
$e$ = coefficient of restitution
Hope it helps! :)